Связать 2 записи о входе и входе без id сессии
Всем привет.
Столкнулся с проблемой компиляции данных для отчетика.
Отчет прост как 2 пальца. Нужно вывести данные о пользователях и их сессиях. Когда воши и когда вышли. Ну и там другие данные, но это не предмет вопроса.
Сложность в том, что каждая запись в БД это либо время входа в систему или время выхода в систему, что логично. Но у этих записей нет ID сессии, по которому можно было бы связать вход и выход между собой.
У записей из ощего только имя пользователя и имя ПК.
Как можно связать 2 записи о входе и выходе в одну ?
Примерно вот так выглядит мой текущий код.
Там еще тянутся данные из другой таблицы, но это значения не играет.
     public async Task<PageData<AgentsWorkingTimeReportData>> GetAgentsWorkingTimeReportAsync(DateTime PeriodFrom, DateTime PeriodTo, List<string> userLogins, int CurrentPage, int PageSize)
 {
     string queryLoginLogout = @"
         SELECT 
             ap_agentid AS AgentId,
             linenumber AS Number,
             login_dt AS LoginDt,
             logout_dt AS LogoutDt
         FROM 
             agent_login_logout_stat
         WHERE 
             (login_dt BETWEEN @PeriodFrom AND @PeriodTo)
             OR 
             (logout_dt BETWEEN @PeriodFrom AND @PeriodTo)
             AND (@UserLogins IS NULL OR ap_agentid = ANY(@UserLogins))
         ORDER BY 
             ap_agentid, login_dt, logout_dt
         LIMIT @PageSize OFFSET @Offset";

     // Запрос из таблицы agentstatusevents_integrated
     string queryAgentStatus = @"
 SELECT 
     ap_agentid AS AgentId,
     cti_workplaceid AS WorkplaceID,
     dt_add AS AddDate
 FROM 
     agentstatusevents_integrated
 WHERE 
     ap_agentid = ANY(@UserLogins)
     AND dt_add BETWEEN @PeriodFrom AND @PeriodTo";

     var parameters = new
     {
         PeriodFrom,
         PeriodTo,
         UserLogins = userLogins?.ToArray(),
         PageSize,
         Offset = (CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize
     };

     using var dbConnection = new NpgsqlConnection(dbConnectionString);

     // Выполнение запросов
     var loginLogoutData = (await dbConnection.QueryAsync<AgentsWorkingTimeReportDataМ>(queryLoginLogout, parameters)).ToList();
     var agentStatusData = (await dbConnection.QueryAsync<AgentStatusData>(queryAgentStatus, parameters)).ToList();

     var totalCountQuery = @"
         SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM agent_login_logout_stat
         WHERE (login_dt BETWEEN @PeriodFrom AND @PeriodTo)
         OR (logout_dt BETWEEN @PeriodFrom AND @PeriodTo)
         AND (@UserLogins IS NULL OR ap_agentid = ANY(@UserLogins))";

     var totalCount = await dbConnection.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>(totalCountQuery, parameters);

     // Объединение данных
     var agentStatusMap = agentStatusData
         .GroupBy(a => a.AgentId)
         .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First().WorkplaceID);

     var responseItems = loginLogoutData.Select(item => new AgentsWorkingTimeReportData
     {
         AgentId = item.AgentId,
         AgentName = userLogins.Contains(item.AgentId) ? item.AgentId : string.Empty,
         Number = item.Number,
         WorkplaceID = agentStatusMap.ContainsKey(item.AgentId) ? agentStatusMap[item.AgentId] : string.Empty,
         LoginDt = item.LoginDt.HasValue ? item.LoginDt.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") : string.Empty,
         LogoutDt = item.LogoutDt.HasValue ? item.LogoutDt.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") : string.Empty
     }).ToList();

     return new PageData<AgentsWorkingTimeReportData>
     {
         Items = responseItems,
         TotalCount = totalCount,
         PageNumber = CurrentPage
     };
 }
 public class AgentStatusData
 {
     public string AgentId { get; set; }
     public string WorkplaceID { get; set; }
     public DateTime AddDate { get; set; }
 }
 public class AgentsWorkingTimeReportDataМ
 {
     public string AgentId { get; set; }
     public string Number { get; set; }
     public DateTime? LoginDt { get; set; }
     public DateTime? LogoutDt { get; set; }
 }

public struct AgentsWorkingTimeReportData
{
    // ID агента
    public string AgentId { get; set; }
    // Имя агента
    public string AgentName { get; set; }
    // Внутренний номер
    public string Number { get; set; }
    // Рабочее место
    public string WorkplaceID { get; set; }
    // Вход в систему
    public string LoginDt { get; set; }
    // Выход из системы
    public string LogoutDt { get; set; }
}

